# How to use template function to sum up the numbers in a string in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

T Sum(T str, T len, T init = 0) {
  T total = init;
  for (T i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    total += (int)str[i];
  }
  return total;
}

int main() {
  string a;
  cout << "Enter a number string: \n";
  cin >> a;
  int n = a.length();
  // Sum<string> s(a);
  int res = Sum(a, n);
  cout << "The SUM of the string is: " << res << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Error:**
error: no matching function for call to 'Sum'
int res = Sum(a, n);
^~~
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T'
('std::basic_string' vs. 'int')
T Sum(T str, T len, T init = 0) {
^
1 error generated.

Comment: Your template requires that all three arguments have the same type `T`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: That means for `Sum<string>`, the signature would look like `string Sum(string str, string len, string init = 0)`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: do not use `using namespace std;`, type `std::` where ever needed, it will save you a lot later on when the program gets bigger, search SO for a larger explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in your template function you are declaring that all your parameters will be of the same type, as well as your return type. I am assuming that that is not what you want. You need to declare a second type:

```
template <class T, class N>
N Sum(T str, N len, N init=0) {
  N total = init;
  for (N i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    total += (int)str[i];
  }
  return total;
}

int main() {
  string a;
  cout << "Enter a number string: \n";
  cin >> a;
  int n = a.length();
  // Sum<string> s(a);
  int res = Sum<string, int>(a, n);
  cout << "The SUM of the string is: " << res << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have copied your code and added the necessary type. This should resolve the problem.

Note: As for the rest of your code, you will not be adding the the integers in your string, but their ASCII values. It seems that is not your intention either.

To fix this you need to modify this line :

```
total += (int)str[i];
```

To this :

```
total += (int)str[i] - 48;
```

As the ASCII value of 0 is 48.

Hope this helps.